# XSL - transforming XML elements to HTML depending on their properties

Tags: xml, xslt

Maybe somebody had similar problem. I need to transform using XSL the input XML file:

```
<decision>
    <akapit nr = 1>
           This is <b>important</b> decision for the query number <i>0123456</i>
    </akapit>
</decision>
```

As output I need a html document which displays text within elements `<b></b>` as bolded, elements in `<i></i>` as italic...etc. So, basically I need to format output HTML from XML element named `<akapit>` depending on their subelements' names. Any idea how to use XSL template in such a case?

Comment: can you show the output that you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case the markup elements names aren't the same as the corresponding Html element names, for example:**

```
<decision>
    <akapit nr="1">
    This is 
        <bold>important</bold> decision for the query number
        <italic>0123456</italic>
    </akapit>
</decision>
```

**Then a very simple application of the [*identity rule*](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) is this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="akapit">
  <div><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="bold"><b><xsl:apply-templates/></b></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="italic"><i><xsl:apply-templates/></i></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And when this transformation is applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<div>
    This is 
        <b>important</b> decision for the query number
        <i>0123456</i>
</div>
```

**Do Note**: Using `xsl:apply-templates` should be preferred to `xsl:copy-of` as the latter doesn't allow flexibility to further process the selected nodes -- it only copies them.

Comment: Great Dimitre, another piece of useful knowledge! I'm starting studying of it!

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach to such problems is

```
<xsl:template match="akapit">
  <div>
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

That should suffice as long as the XML input uses the same elements for e.g. bold or italic as HTML uses.

If you have other elements in the input XML e.g.

```
<decision>
    <akapit nr = 1>
           This is <bold>important</bold> decision for the query number <i>0123456</i>
    </akapit>
</decision>
```

then you need to transform stuff e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="akapit">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="akapit//*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="akapit//bold">
  <b>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </b>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just use `copy-of` to duplicate everything under your `akapit` element.

```
<xsl:template match="/decision/akapit[@nr='1']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: To be more specific, the elements <i>and <b> are as example, in real xml I need to process elements within <italic> and <bold> elements, so simple duplicate everything under akapit element, as I assume, do not transfer into proper HTML tags (here <i> and <b>).

Comment: @slawek OK, I thought you had raw HTML in your `akapit` element. You will need to provide mapping rules for each of your own markup 'tags' which translates each to the equivalent html.